# Android- read incoming messages using broadcast receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have created an android application that listens for incoming sms. The issue i am encountering is that it also reads previous sms. The goal of the app was to grab sms from a  specific originating address and store it in a database.

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO: This method is called when the BroadcastReceiver is receiving
        // an Intent broadcast.
        Log.i(TAG, "Intent Received: "+intent.getAction());
        if (intent.getAction()==SMS_RECEIVED){
            Bundle dataBundle = intent.getExtras();
            if(dataBundle != null){
                //creating PDU protocol Data unit object which is a protocol for transferring message
                Object[] mypdu = (Object[])dataBundle.get("pdus");
                final SmsMessage[] message = new SmsMessage[mypdu.length];

                for(int i =0; i< mypdu.length; i++){
                    //for build version >= API
                    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
                        String format = dataBundle.getString("format");
                        //From PDU we get all object and smsMessage using following line of code
                        message[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])mypdu[i],format);
                    }else{
                        message[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) mypdu[i]);
                    }
                    msg += message[i].getMessageBody().toString().replace("null","");
                    originatingAddress = message[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                }
                msg = msg.replace("null","");
                if(originatingAddress.trim().equals("MPESA")) {
                    Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "message: " + msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        }
//        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");

    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by address? phone number?

Comment: sorry I meant originating address

Comment: The code you shared should work for that, should not read the previous SMS. But you can filter it by phone number. Then you will get the SMS only from the specific phone number.

Comment: Yeah it actually works. But sometimes i get  more than one entry of the same sms in database

Comment: Then you have to check the object is the same or not before inserting it in DB.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below way
(1)The Simple way you can achieve to store the unique of record on every SMS is timestamp is only unique in this case whenever you get SMS store timestamp of every Sms as a Unique or primary key as you want in database, like system.currentTimeMillisecond to get time of current SMS and store as LONG type Column in your database,

(2) you can also check with unique time on every SMS get but it is complex to check with every existing records

Hope this process will help in your way with prevent of duplicate record store in database

Comment: I actually have a unique column to store message code. The huge problem am facing is that the receiver still reads the previous message when a new incoming message comes.

Comment: try to clear the intent after use in onReceive, if still facing then try another way like you can save for more uniqueness of message like time, code and string messages on every sms in  3 or more global variable and then check this  more params with before store sms data in db........hope it will help you

Comment: Just found out that when i kill the app then launch it again after each receive it works fine. How can i reset it after receiving.

Comment: You can reset it with new value on every SMS after store in database and add validation before store in DB. Please declare this variable in application class so it will be better to use anywhere and reset where you want with application singleton instance